# Smooth scrolling in Android

Tags: android, scroll

There is an app in the market place called Floating images. This app has one of the smoothest scrolling logic. Basically the app has a blank canvas covering whole screen and then there are some images displayed on top of the blank canvas. User can swipe and the app moves the image in the direction of swipe. Plus it does kinetic scrolling too. Plus there are no scrollbars so it seems like the developer has created a custom view implementing all smooth scrolling logic.

it would be awesome if i could get the source of it.. but anyone has any pseudo code or logic on how to implement this kind of feature. Any leads , site links would be helpful.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I have no experience with OpenGL nor accelerometer, but swipe (called *fling* in Android's API) is not hard to achieve. First thing you need when making such a custom `View`, is implementing a `GestureDetector` and call its `onTouchEvent()` in your view's `onTouchEvent()`

```
GestureDetector mGD = new GestureDetector(getContext(),
                                        new SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                                float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        // beware, it can scroll to infinity
        scrollBy((int)distanceX, (int)distanceY);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float vX, float vY) {
        mScroller.fling(getScrollX(), getScrollY(),
                -(int)vX, -(int)vY, 0, (int)mMaxScrollX, 0, (int)mMaxScrollY);
        invalidate(); // don't remember if it's needed
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        if(!mScroller.isFinished() ) { // is flinging
            mScroller.forceFinished(true); // to stop flinging on touch
        }
        return true; // else won't work
    }
});

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return mGD.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

While `OnGestureListener.onScroll()` calls directly `View.scrollBy()`, for the `onFling()` method you'll need a `Scroller`.

`Scroller` is a simple object that, as reference says, encapsulates scrolling. It can be used for continuous scrolling or to react to flings. Scroller.fling() begin a "simulation" of fling scroll inside itself, and by watching it you can copy its smoothness with a continuous redrawing animation:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // ....your drawings....

    // scrollTo invalidates, so until animation won't finish it will be called
    // (used after a Scroller.fling() )
    if(mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
        scrollTo(mScroller.getCurrX(), mScroller.getCurrY());
    }
}
```

that is, until animation is running, calculate the point we reached and scroll there.

As a last note: remember to return `true` in your `OnGestureListener.onDown()`, even if you don't want to do anything on down, or it won't work.

And be careful, because `Scroller` in Android 2.2 has a bug for which the fling animation will not actually end even if it reaches the limits you passed as arguments (yet computed offset respects them, so it won't actually move).

Comment: Thanks bigstones. Looks like that i have to read some more to understand your sample and make my code work. I really appreciate your effort to provide code snippet and explanation.

Comment: Nice explanation bro for beginner but can you please tell me what is mScroller in this I mean where it is intialize ?

Comment: @user1201239 you can initalize it in the constructor.

Comment: @bigstones : mScroller will be of the type ? am i right ? mScroller = new GestureDetector(context,this);   mScroller.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);  It wont be setonDOubleTapListener right ?

Comment: @user1201239, no it's `Scroller mScroller = new Scroller(this);`

Comment: A complete example here: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/making-interactive.html

Comment: Thanx for this.. It helped me to start with scrolling bit..The problem is if the content is more than the area of screen and I try to scroll it still doesn't show the content and instead its all blank..

Comment: @bigstones can you help me on this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354263/catch-ontouch-event-by-custom-2d-scrollview-parent-handle-it-and-pass-to-childr

Comment: Thanks! Bigstones ! works fine! however I'm drawing shapeDrawables in _onDraw(Canvas canvas)_   when we scroll shapeDrawable's the bound changes ! is there any method to change/update the already displayed bounds ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376601/how-to-update-android-shapedrawable-bounds-changes-after-implimenting-scroller-w

Answer (score 8):

The Floating Images app is an open source project. 
http://code.google.com/p/floatingimage/

Comment: @rallat : it'not relate to Android.

Comment: @Shubh It is very much so Android related. He provided a link to an open source Android project called "floatingimage" with the app's description of "Show an image stream on your android phone"