# Scrolling images across the screen in android

Tags: android

I'm writing an application in which i have to scroll different images one after another across the screen. In order to do that, i create a list of 10 ImageView items. These image view items are placed one after another like train coaches.

The question is how to scroll them from left to right. I thought of using scrollview, but it can accept only one child component and does vertical scrolling.

There is a Scroller class, but i'm not sure how to use it, i mean what does it scroll? I dont see any method like Scroller.scroll(view).

Another approach which i though was to user Layout animation such as TranslateAnimation, but then the end result is kind of shaky.

Can anyone point me to some sample of scrolling image from left to write. I don't want to use the gallery components because it defeats the objective of the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use `HorizontalScrollView` with a horizontal `LinearLayout` inside, containing your `ImageViews`.

Comment: But then how automatic scrolling of Imageview will happen. Do i still have to use the animation class?

Comment: @prasrob for automatic scrolling there's Scroller.startScroll().

Comment: You could also try smoothScrollTo in scrollview

Comment: I wonder of Scroller class can be used with any view except TextView. Only this class seems to have setScroller method?

Comment: @prasrob the idea should be the same I've shown you in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951142/smooth-scrolling-in-android/4951681#4951681

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HorizontalScrollView` with a horizontal `LinearLayout` inside, containing your `ImageViews`.

You can do one more thing to override the following method in `horizantalScrollview`

```
@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
       //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Gallery widget would much help you