# Smooth scrolling with inertia and edge resistance/snapback

Tags: java, android, touch

I implemented basic scrolling via touch dragging and multitouch zooming for a custom view. This works well, but now I'd like to add some advanced features.

For example, in the Google Maps application, when you drag around the screen, after you stop dragging it will still continue to move a bit (inertia). And some browsers (e.g. IPad Safari) allow you to drag the screen further than the visible area of the website, but then the screen will quickly snap back to the edge of the website.

I'd now like to implement something similar, but to do that I need to change the active screen region *after* the touch events happened in regular intervals to perform the animation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a [OnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html). To provide smooth scroll, create a scroller (in your custom view). When the gesture listener detects a fling event, set the scroller up. Then, override your custom view's computeScroll() method.

Check this example to know how to implement it.

```
int lastX;
int lastY;
Scroller scroller;    
@Override
public void computeScroll() {
  if (scroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
    if (!scrolledLastFrame) {
      lastX = scroller.getStartX();
      lastY = scroller.getStartY();
    }

    int dx = scroller.getCurrX() - lastX;
    int dy = scroller.getCurrY() - lastY;

    lastX = scroller.getCurrX();
    lastY = scroller.getCurrY();

    doScroll(dx, dy);
    scrolledLastFrame = true;
  } else {
    scrolledLastFrame = false;
  }

}    

public void doFling(int startX, int startY, int velocityX, int velocityY,
    int minX, int maxX, int minY, int maxY) {
  scroller.fling(startX, startY, velocityX, velocityY, minX, maxX, minY, maxY);
  invalidate();
}

public void doScroll(int dx, int dy) {
  currentX+=dx;
  currentY+=dy;

  invalidate();
}

private class ProgramGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
        float distanceX, float distanceY) {

      doScroll(distanceX, distanceY);
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
      int max_left = getMaxHorizontalScroll();
      int max_top = getMaxVerticalScroll();
      int min_left = getMinHorizontalScroll();
      int min_top = getMinVerticalScroll();

      int startX = getCurrentHorizontalScroll();
      int startY = getCurrentVerticalScroll();

      doFling(startX, startY, (int) -velocityX, (int) -velocityY,
          min_left, max_left, min_top, max_top);

      return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I didn't know about computeScroll(), it's way better than use computeScrollOffset() inside onDraw() like I did. +1

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to implement a solution based on your answer, but my computeScroll() is not called for some reason. Do I have to connect Scroller and View somehow?

Comment: to use a GestureListener, you also need to use a GestureDetector. Send touch events to the detector and set the ProgramGestureListener as the detector's listener. Maybe useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Scroller](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html) class, I posted an example of use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951142/smooth-scrolling-in-android/4951681#4951681).

If you're on API 9 you could use [OverScroller](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/OverScroller.html) I think.