# Scrolling lag with GestureDetector onScroll

Tags: android, scroll, touch

I use `GestureDetector` to implement scrolling inside a custom `View`. My implementation is based on this: [Smooth scrolling with inertia and edge resistance/snapback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003069/smooth-scrolling-with-inertia-and-edge-resistance-snapback/5003186#5003186)

I noticed a short pause before the scrolling starts: I examined the `onScroll` messages and noticed that the first one arrives only after a larger movement of a finger, which causes noticable lag at the beginning of the scrolling. After that the scrolling is smooth.

It seems `GestureDetector` starts sending `onScroll` messages only after a minimal distance between the motionevents to make sure the gesture is not a longtap or tap (btw I set `setIsLongpressEnabled(false)`).

Is there any way to change this behaviour and create a smooth scroll without implementing a custom scroll gesture using low level touch events?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is no, you have to create your own `GestureDetector`. If you look at the Android source code ([GestureDetector.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/view/GestureDetector.java)) lines 524 to 540 are use to detect the "touch slop" for a single tap.  Specifically line 528 prevents the `onScroll` event from being called until the movement is outside the touch slop (which is pulled from the view configuration).  You cannot change the view configuration and the slop is hard coded at 16 pixels.  This is the radius that causes the lag that you are seeing.

Comment: Or you just set mTouchSlopSquare with reflection after the constructor (do this only if you care about onScroll and nothing else).

    `private fun GestureDetector.hackTouchSlop() {
        try {
            val touchSlopField = javaClass.getDeclaredField("mTouchSlopSquare")
            touchSlopField.isAccessible = true
            touchSlopField.set(this, 0)
        } catch (ignored: Throwable) {
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to change `mTouchSlopSquare` from [GestureDetector.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java)

```
    public static void setGestureDetectorTouchSlop(GestureDetector gestureDetector, int value) {
        try {
            Field f_mTouchSlopSquare = GestureDetector.class.getDeclaredField("mTouchSlopSquare");
            f_mTouchSlopSquare.setAccessible(true);
            f_mTouchSlopSquare.setInt(gestureDetector, value * value);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException | NullPointerException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, gestureDetector.toString(), e);
        }
    }
```

Also, here is the method to change the slop for the [GestureDetectorCompat.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/0bb301e/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/GestureDetectorCompat.java)

```
    public static void setGestureDetectorTouchSlop(GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector, int value) {
        try {
            Field f_mImpl = GestureDetectorCompat.class.getDeclaredField("mImpl");
            f_mImpl.setAccessible(true);
            Object mImpl = f_mImpl.get(gestureDetector);
            if (mImpl == null) {
                Log.w(TAG, f_mImpl + " is null");
                return;
            }
            Class<?> c_GDCIJellybeanMr2 = null;
            Class<?> c_GDCIBase = null;
            try {
                c_GDCIJellybeanMr2 = Class.forName(GestureDetectorCompat.class.getName() + "$GestureDetectorCompatImplJellybeanMr2");
                c_GDCIBase = Class.forName(GestureDetectorCompat.class.getName() + "$GestureDetectorCompatImplBase");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
            }
            if (c_GDCIJellybeanMr2 != null && c_GDCIJellybeanMr2.isInstance(mImpl)) {
                Field f_mDetector = c_GDCIJellybeanMr2.getDeclaredField("mDetector");
                f_mDetector.setAccessible(true);

                Object mDetector = f_mDetector.get(mImpl);
                if (mDetector instanceof GestureDetector)
                    setGestureDetectorTouchSlop((GestureDetector) mDetector, value);
            } else if (c_GDCIBase != null) {
                Field f_mTouchSlopSquare = c_GDCIBase.getDeclaredField("mTouchSlopSquare");
                f_mTouchSlopSquare.setAccessible(true);
                f_mTouchSlopSquare.setInt(mImpl, value * value);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "not handled: " + mImpl.getClass().toString());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException | NullPointerException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, gestureDetector.getClass().toString(), e);
        }
    }
```