# Cant define smoothScrollBy

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to use the Android Music app's TouchInterceptor class to allow a user to reorder a ListView.

It can be found [here.](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/com/android/music/TouchInterceptor.java;hb=HEAD)

I've copied the file and created the necessary resources.

However, I'm left with 1 error.  The method smoothScrollBy is undefined.

I'm using API 7 (2.1).  Does it not exist in 2.1?  If so, what should I be using?  I'd really like to target the application to users at least running 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

[smoothScrollBy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollBy%28int,%20int%29) is in API level 8, which is Froyo (2.2).

You may have to settle for [scrollBy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollBy%28int,%20int%29), which has been around since API level 1.

Edit: for this specific problem, perhaps take a look at an [earlier version](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/music/TouchInterceptor.java;h=6c22e7234dcae7ceda5fd159637273c60449f32f;hb=0749a3f1c11e052f97a3ba60fd624c9283ee7331) of TouchInterceptor.java that was written for 2.1.

Comment: Is there an alternative I can use?

Comment: Not in ListView. You can create your own list class though if scrollBy won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider doing a backport, at least see if it's doable (or might there be license issues?). The source is [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java&q=smoothscrollby&exact_package=git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/frameworks/base.git&l=3214). Knowing [how to implement fling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951142/smooth-scrolling-in-android/4951681#4951681) could be useful too.