# SurfaceView onDraw mimic of a decelerating user movement

Tags: android, surfaceview, touch-event

I implemented a custom android SurfaceView class which draw (onDraw method) something often bigger than the available device width and height. When the user toutch the screen and move it's finger I need to implement a kind of picture movement with a speed and direction matching the speed and direction given by the user. That part I'm able to do it within onTouchEvent method. But here is my question: now I also want the speed to decelerate progressivly. I think this probably have to be coded with DecelerateInterpolator... Is there some samples or demos somewhere involving a SurfaceView, onTouchEvent and DecelerateInterpolator... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking of a too complicated way to address the problem. Finally found a way to solve my problem here: [Smooth scrolling in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951142/smooth-scrolling-in-android) The OnGestureListener simplify all gestures management.