# How to Handle TouchEvents for Child View(CustomView) in Parent View (ScrollView)?

Tags: android, scrollview, ontouchlistener, custom-view

In my app i am using `ScrollView` for scrolling the `ImageView`, and i will add one customview dynamically to that `ScrollView` overlay of `ImageView`, i have `onTouch` events for customview. after adding to the scroll view i am not able to use the touch listeners of customview, still scrollview was working on that.

how to stop the scrollview touch listeners, and how to enable our custom view touch listeners..

Comment: Touch listeners events are not supported in ScrollView.

Comment: ok, this is my requirement: ImageView overlay CustomView for paint using finger, and scroll the image if it is larger than physical display. how to solve this.

Comment: @Balaji, is it possible or not to add a CustomView with touch listeners as a ScrollView Child..

Comment: In question you are saying ScrollView  as Parent and in above comment as Child??

Comment: i.e customview child for scrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you not to go with `ScrollView`. Simply add your custom view in `LinearLayout` and implement `OnGestureListener` and then using `GestureDetector` you can able to listen all events(like onDown(),onFling(),onScroll(),onSingleTapUp(),onDown(),etc). You can sense scroll magnitudes and then by using `scrollBy()` method you can scroll your image(custom view). For more detilas you can refer following posts:
[Smooth scrolling in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951142/smooth-scrolling-in-android)

Comment: i have one more solution for scrolling by using onTouchListeners, but problem is i am not able to synchronous scrolling of imageview and customview. if i scroll imageview, not able to scroll the customview with same distance from x and y.