# How to scroller scroll smoothly?

Tags: java, android

My problem is when I'm using scroller and draw canvas on it. It will scroll smoothly but when I draw bitmap + canvas the scroller scroll very slow means it is heavy to scroll thats why it scroll very slow fashion.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, your question was answered by an unethical user.  I'd suggest you check this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951142/smooth-scrolling-in-android

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with `OpenGL` nor accelerometer, but swipe (called fling in Android's API) is not hard to achieve. First thing you need when making such a custom View, is implementing a `GestureDetector` and call its `onTouchEvent()` in your view's `onTouchEvent()`

```
GestureDetector mGD = new GestureDetector(getContext(),
                                        new SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                                float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        // beware, it can scroll to infinity
        scrollBy((int)distanceX, (int)distanceY);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float vX, float vY) {
        mScroller.fling(getScrollX(), getScrollY(),
                -(int)vX, -(int)vY, 0, (int)mMaxScrollX, 0, (int)mMaxScrollY);
        invalidate(); // don't remember if it's needed
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        if(!mScroller.isFinished() ) { // is flinging
            mScroller.forceFinished(true); // to stop flinging on touch
        }
        return true; // else won't work
    }
});

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return mGD.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

While `OnGestureListener.onScroll()` calls directly `View.scrollBy()`, for the `onFling()` method you'll need a Scroller.

`Scroller` is a simple object that, as reference says, encapsulates scrolling. It can be used for continuous scrolling or to react to flings. `Scroller.fling()` begin a "simulation" of fling scroll inside itself, and by watching it you can copy its smoothness with a continuous redrawing animation:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // ....your drawings....

    // scrollTo invalidates, so until animation won't finish it will be called
    // (used after a Scroller.fling() )
    if(mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
        scrollTo(mScroller.getCurrX(), mScroller.getCurrY());
    }
}
```

that is, until animation is running, calculate the point we reached and scroll there.

As a last note: remember to return true in your `OnGestureListener.onDown()`, even if you don't want to do anything on down, or it won't work.

And be careful, because `Scroller` in Android 2.2 has a bug for which the fling animation will not actually end even if it reaches the limits you passed as arguments (yet computed offset respects them, so it won't actually move).

Comment: Hi Mike, thanx for reply.this concept it is working fine when only canvas is draw bt when i m draw image + canvas(bitmap) it is not working properly bcoz its heavy.