# WebView Smooth Scrolling Issue

Tags: android, webview, smooth-scrolling

In my one of my android app ,I am using the WebView to render the html content. Whenever we scroll the Webview horizontally/vertically there is a jerk(shake) in the webview content.I have opened the lot of websites in android browser app. But the browser also have the same issue. But when we open the "Play Books" application, there is no jerks in scrolling.This app has the smooth scrolling. I am assuming that "Play Books" also using the android WebView. How can I achieve the smooth scrolling same as "Play Books" horizontal scrolling in the android webview. I am using android 4.0+.

Answer (score 2):

Actually play books interface is made by Google where they have best programmers :(

Take a look at this it may help you [Smooth scrolling in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951142/smooth-scrolling-in-android) !!