# Scrolling speed of scrollview containing multiple recyclerview is slow

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

Following is the content of `activitymain`

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:elevation="40dp"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Following is the content of `content_main`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.cardview.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/viewBg">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <CustomView
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
        custom:auto_cycle="true"
        custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
        custom:pager_animation_span="1100"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>

    <CustomView
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        custom:selected_color="#0095BF"
        custom:unselected_color="#55333333"
        custom:selected_drawable="@drawable/bird"
        custom:shape="oval"
        custom:selected_padding_left="5dp"
        custom:selected_padding_right="5dp"
        custom:unselected_padding_left="5dp"
        custom:unselected_padding_right="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        custom:selected_width="6dp"
        custom:selected_height="6dp"
        custom:unselected_width="6dp"
        custom:unselected_height="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        />
    <CustomView
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator2"
        style="@style/AndroidImageSlider_Corner_Oval_Orange"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/titleOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Top Ten Songs"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:theme="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="See More..."
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/first"/>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/horizontal_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/titleTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Top Ten Songs"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMores"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:theme="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="See More..."
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@+id/second"
        android:id="@+id/vertical_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

i have included content main within activity main.
content main has got two recycler views. One recycler view is horizontal recyclerview. Second recyclerview is vertical recyclerview.

The problem is that the scrolling speed is too slow. And the scrollview does not scroll to the end of the page at a single instance. how can i be able to sort this out?

Comment: scrolling speed depend of the velocity of your fling gesture

Comment: though i fling it fast, the speed is still low

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143485/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-not-scrolling-smoothly