# how to do smooth scrolling with nested scroll view inside coordinator layout

Tags: android

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="">

            <fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.mydermacy.www.beyou.activities.CompareClinicsActivity" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_clinics"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rc_clinic_compare"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:behavior_overlapTop="184dp"
            android:background="@color/background" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <!--app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have layout with `CoordinatorLayout` as a rootview and inside that I have two child view `AppBarLayout` and `NestedScrollView`. I am not able to do smooth scrolling. What can be done to achieve smooth scrolling?

Comment: I don't think you need to put RecyclerView into a NestedScrollView. It may also prevents the RecyclerView to "recycle". That should be source your problem.

Comment: if I remove the nested scroll view then the recycle view  gets position in top and actually I want it like when user scrolls up the card then map fragment view gets hide and title will be displayed that's why I have used appbarlayout and I have to use nested view for that.

Comment: Try making your own LayoutManager with canScrollVertically() returning false as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41134806/2900210

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CoordinatorLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` smooth scroll is **bug** and Google still has not fixed it. :|

remove `NestedScrollView`. `RecyclerView` with `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` That's enough and fix.

you can use third party library : [smooth-app-bar-layout](https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout)

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for. I haven't yet tried it but looks like a perfect one. Thanks. Upvoted 

Comment: Didn't work for me but using this helped. Setting on my recyclerview to disable nested scrolling with this. 
            recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:title="">

        <fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.mydermacy.www.beyou.activities.CompareClinicsActivity" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_clinics"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rc_clinic_compare"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="184dp"
        android:background="@color/background" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<!--app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />-->
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

i removed the nested scroll view and app:behavior_overlapTop="184dp" from recycle view so the problem got solved also i added app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to recycle view thanks for help