# What is wrong with this RecyclerView ViewHolder ScrollView layout that wont scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I my `RecyclerView` `ViewHolder` layout I try to put an  `android.widget.ScrollView` to scroll the content like this this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <android.widget.ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="SOME TEXT"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descr_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title_text"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="SOME TEXT"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView
                android:id="@+id/progress_view"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:cpv_indeterminate="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.widget.ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is nothing happens I cannot scroll it. 
Any suggestions would be grate?

Comment: Did you try these?
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083091/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-is-not-working)
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143485/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-not-scrolling-smoothly)

Comment: Have you try to put a height in dp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `RecyclerView` is already scrolling, you probably need [NestedScrollview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html).

Comment: Thanks your right. I scroll but really slow, I have to swipe really easy and slow to get the scroll moving